# Google cloud datastore API cannot find project when App Engine application is disabled

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to connect and get data from Google Cloud Datastore API.

After disabling my App Engine Application (which have no use for me at the moment), I cannot access any GC Datastore API methods.

When I send my request, I always get the following response:

```
{ [Error: The project [my-project] does not exist.] code: 404, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
```

I've already double-checked this and my project name is correct.

Accessing the google cloud console, I noticed that the datastore dashboard also show the same message:

[image: error message]

Then, after enabling the app engine application again, everything works.

I know that GC Datastore was initially created to work with App Engine, but since last year it was supposed to be available everywhere (according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMC_k0NBjKs)).

Someone have a tip about this issue? Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Cloud Datastore API currently requires that the associated App Engine application not be disabled.

I've filed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/107 to track this. It's something we may be able to fix in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your response and for addressing the issue. Regards