# The project 'test-dev' does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore database

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to run the test for project created in google cloud, but i am facing below error,

```
Error: The project 'test-dev' does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore database. 
Please visit http://console.cloud.google.com to create a project or https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=test-dev to add a Cloud Datastore database. 
Note that Cloud Datastore always has an associated App Engine app and this app must not be disabled.
```

Anybody face this error ever before, and how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560659/google-cloud-datastore-api-cannot-find-project-when-app-engine-application-is-di

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem when following the Datastore API tutorial:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial

My problem went away when I re-defined the project id as a new project's ID. In the case of the tutorial I set DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=NEW_ID

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I encountered *exactly* the same error when trying to follow one of the Python on Google Compute Engine tutorials:

https://cloud.google.com/python/tutorials/bookshelf-on-compute-engine

Fortunately, your error message (where "test-dev" is the project name):

```
Please visit http://console.cloud.google.com to create a project
or https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=test-dev
to add a Cloud Datastore database.
```

Tells you **exactly** what do be done: click on the second link, and set up a Cloud Datastore, under your chosen project name. The tutorial I was following seemed to assume that one would be set up immediately (which it wasn't). Make that database, and things should be well (or better).

Note: for November 2018, you might get something like "Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore": you may be prompted for both. I chose Datastore, as Firestore is beta.