# Project does not exists or it does not contain an Active Cloud DataStore

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application on Google Cloud Platform that uses FireStore as the Database.

I am getting this error when trying to insert records on FireStore.

```
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 The project "book-shop-c73ec" does not
exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore database. Please visit ht
tp://console.cloud.google.com to create a project or https://console.cloud.googl
e.com/datastore/setup?project="book-shop-c73ec" to add a Cloud Datastore databas
e. Note that Cloud Datastore always has an associated App Engine app and this ap
p must not be disabled.
```

This is the sample code I am using.

```
from google.cloud import firestore

# Add a new document
db = firestore.Client()
doc_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(u'alovelace')
doc_ref.set({
    u'first': u'Ada',
    u'last': u'Lovelace',
    u'born': 1815
})

# Then query for documents
users_ref = db.collection(u'users')
docs = users_ref.get()

for doc in docs:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

My application is enabled on app engine :

[image]

And when I go to the DataStore Tab, I am pointed to FireStore.

[image]

Did I miss any step here?

Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560659/google-cloud-datastore-api-cannot-find-project-when-app-engine-application-is-di), but its just suggesting to enable the app on app engine, which I already did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just an error on my environment variable on windows.

I had set it  to

```
set GCLOUD_PROJECT="project-name"
```

instead

```
set GCLOUD_PROJECT=project-name
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having this exact error, but my problem was that app engine was disabled in the project, enabling it solved the problem and I was able to upgrade to Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

**GCLOUD_PROJECT** is already deprecated in favor of **GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT**, where btw you are expected to set **the project id and not the name**!