# Firebase Cloud Function Showing As Offline

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I just had something weird happen, and I wanted to see if anyone knew of a way to fix it. I have had an app deployed in App Engine, 3 Cloud Functions, and a Firestore repository going for a while. Long story short, I moved my application from App Engine, so disabled it. However, I still wanted my functions to work as well as keep my Firestore. However, once I disabled App Engine, my functions were showing as offline and my Firestore was disabled until I re-enabled App Engine. I am a little perplexed by this. I don't want my App Engine instance anymore. Any ideas how I can disable App Engine and still have my Cloud Functions working and firestore available?

Comment: Please elaborate on the question. Are you using Firebase Functions and Firestore or Cloud Functions and Firestore?

Comment: Might be related; I had some cloud functions (no Firebase) that were just showing up as `OFFLINE` on `gcloud` output, without any explanation; but [the web dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list) showed more details (error messages, to be precise) regarding why the functions were offline. But I guess you've already tried that via the Firebase console :)

Comment: I am using firebase functions (which are Google cloud functions in reality) and Firestore. It was strange that I couldn't run my functions or access my Firestore without enabling my app engine app again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Firestore relies on Cloud Datastore, which in turn relies on Google App Engine. Here's a [Medium blogpost about the issue](https://medium.com/likecoin/disabling-google-app-engine-disabled-my-sites-database-25408acbd2df).

In the [Cloud Datastore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-mobile-web#create_a_cloud_firestore_project) there's a note referencing the close relation between the three components:

> **Cloud Firestore and App Engine**: You can't use both Cloud Firestore and Cloud Datastore in the same project, which might affect apps using App Engine. Try using Cloud Firestore with a different project if you need to use Cloud Datastore.

Also, this [StackOverflow answer by a Googler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36561430/9908251) stating that GAE needs to be enabled for Cloud Datastore to work.

---

To summarize, GAE has to be enabled to use Cloud Datastore and the project has to be able to use Cloud Datastore for Cloud Firestore to work.